# How check several atrribute changes in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a model `user` with two attributes: name and surname.
I want to update it, so I display a prefilled form where name and surname are alredy filled. After that I need to save update model with code, but before this I have to check whether model changed or not:

```
this.model.set("name", formData.name);
this.model.set("surname", formData.surname);
if (this.model.hasChanged()) {
    this.model.save();
}
```

Consider the situation when only name is changed in the from:

```
this.model.set("name", formData.name);
//this.model.hasChanged() -> true
this.model.set("surname", formData.surname);
//this.model.hasChanged() -> false
if (this.model.hasChanged()) {
    //so model do not changes at all :(
}
```

Is there a way to check that all model attributes changed? (not one by one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest changing the way you set the model attributes, and instead set them all at once.  This will allow the `change` event to fire only once if *any* attributes change during the model set operation.

```js
this.model.set({
    name: formData.name,
    surname: formData.surname
});

if (this.model.hasChanged()) {
    // executes this code...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> After that I need to save update model with code, but before this I
>   have to check whether model changed or not:

Why do you want to explicitly check whether `model` is changed. You can directly bind a `change` event on `model` and then save it. In that case if and only if model (any attribute in model) is changed it will fire a `change` event.

Try this :

```
this.model.on('change', function () {
    this.model.save();
}, this);
```

Have a look at [model.set](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-set) and [event](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-on).

Comment: Because change event is sent every time when model attribute is changed. For exampel if there 15 attributes, with your code model will be saved 15 times. Which is not good practise.

Comment: Thanks @Cherry for your comment. My concern was about the check `if (this.model.hasChanged())` why is that needed? Also, if you set your model with an entire hash and NOT one property at a time the `change` event would be fired only once. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/niranjan_borawake/d78Kt/3/) is what I had thought. Thanks again.